# Рисование в java

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток уважаемые коллеги, интересует следующее - есть ли в java ( или каких либо библиотеках, расширениях и т.д., не суть важна ), возможность рисовать, например как на javascript'e на canvas'e...

Если такая возможность есть - поделитесь пожалуйста ссылками на книги, статьи и т.д. Так-же, если вас не затруднит, не отказался бы от примерчика ( конечно-же если код небольшой ).

Интересует именно самостоятельное приложение, так-же интересует, опять таки если это возможно :), соизмеримо ли это по скорости, хотя-бы с webgl...

PS: так-же интересно - есть ли какая-либо возможность взаимодействия с ресурсами видеокарты...
PPS: пока кроме JavaFX ничего в голову не лезет... Но это, мягко говоря, не то...

Заранее спасибо, понять и разобраться очень важно - выручайте :)

Comment: Мне тоже интересно. Читал, что есть JOGL. Но что она из себя представляет, не знаю.

Comment: Благодарочка хоть за какуето инфу, если не будет других предложений в течении 2-3ех дней потестю...

Comment: А <a href="http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/index.jsp">Java 2D</a> это не то?

Comment: нет, не то...<br>
В википедии мельком упяменули о java3d... Так вот это уже ближе.<br>
Но колличество инфы ~= 0 :(<br>
Почему именно java? потомучто по определению кроссплатформа...<br>
Почему мне мало java 2d? Да потомучто я могу без проблем реализовать это в html canvas'e :)<br>

Идея имнно в кроссплатформенности быстрых независимых решений....

Comment: Поискал еще в интернете. Нашел такие:

 * [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) 
 * [jzy3d](http://code.google.com/p/jzy3d/)

А Java3D - это, похоже, надстройка на JOGL, а JOGL - просто обертка OpenGL.

Comment: А я где-то писал что я против OpenGL?<br>
Спасибо большое за предоставленную инфу, предчувствую что мои "копания" по этому вопросу затянутся надолго :)<br>
да и, если на то пошло - <b>lwjgl</b> тоже имеет привязку к OpenGL ;)
<br>
Тем не менее большое спасибо з предоставленную инфу, опять таки покопаюсь если не предложат "МЕГО" вариантов, и поделюсьт своими впечатлениями :)

Comment: Мне нужно написать курсовую работу с использованием OpenGL. Думаю использовать Java (другой вариант - Delphi). Поэтому мне будет очень полезна эта информация.

Comment: Ждем "великого гуру" и его ответа или бум сами копаться :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я не понимаю о чём вы говорите и никак не понимаю, почему речь сразу зашла про OpenGL?

Вопрос поставлен

> есть ли в java (...) возможность рисовать, например как на javascript'e на canvas'e...

Разумеется, есть. Это называется Java2D. И никаких библиотек не требует.

Если же речь действительно про OpenGL, то есть JOGL. JOGL - это просто враппер, который просто объявляет почти все OpenGL-функции. Соответственно, они будут иметь такое же именование и прототипы функций аналогиченые оригинальным.

По поводу ресурсов видеокарты, то тут всё зависит от того, с какими ключами запущена виртуальная машина. Можно сделать так, чтобы она не использовала ничего и тогда она будет иметь возможность рисовать изображения даже без видеокарты и иксов. Или можно включить использование DirectX или OpenGL (на юниксах, разумеется, только второе) и тогда аппаратное ускорение будет использоваться для ускорения рисования 2D.

Что же до 3D, то насколько мне известно, использовать можно всё то же, что и обычно можно делать на OpenGL, но работает это немного медленнее. Однако, это не будет большой проблемой, если не использовать старые OpenGL-функции. Надо экономить вызовы нативных методов.

**UPD**

Сравнивать их производительности просто смешно. Не думаете же вы, что javascript + canvas имеют какие-то серьёзные шансы против Java2D? Но думаю, такие сравнения кто-нибудь уже проводил, можно поискать. Я уж не говрою о том, что возможности у канваса, мягко говоря ограниченные. С другой стороны, весьма вероятно, что вам ничего особенного и не нужно. Если надо нарисовать пару линий и пару квадратов, то может и не стоит заваривать кашу.

Вот вам краткий пример использования Java2D.. уж извините, но что-то воображение у меня к ночи не очень, так что пусть будет флаг

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(320, 240, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();

        try {
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 320, 240);

            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HBGR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(30.f));

            g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 320, 240);
            g2d.drawLine(0, 240, 320, 0);

            g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 25));

            g2d.drawString("1712", 130, 60);
        } finally {
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", new File("test.png"));
    }
}
```

test.png:

[image: Результат]

**UPD2**

На самом деле, если подумать, то HTML-Canvas + JavaScript имеют шансы на каких-то простых вещах. Скорее всего разница будет просто напросто незаметна, пока не начнёте рисовать что-то грандиозное. Так что если вы думаете делать какой-нибудь апплет, чтобы нарисовать кружок с точкой, то не стоит этого делать :))

**UPD3**

В Java есть ещё ряд преимуществ, которые приходят в голову, если смотреть задачу вроде той, что вы описываете (что-то похожее на какую-то игру или карту, как я понимаю). Главное - простота занесения внешних картинок из ресурсов и возможность кэширования некоторых частей нарисованного, что может быть очень полезно, когда рисовать надо много и часто. У кансваса с этим будут проблемы.

Непомерные числа, о которых вы говорите скорее говорят не о проблемах со средством рисования, а о проблеме с тем, как вы рисуете. Очевидно, что если пропускной способности чего-либо не хватает, то это значит, что надо уменьшить численность каким-то образом. Слияние/объединение, фильтрация, отсечение и т.п. помогут уменьшить количество элементов до приемлемой величины. Думаю, вам надо поинтересоваться методами в компьютерной графике и геймдевом, в частности.

**UPD4**

И последнее: если захотите использовать мой пример, чтобы что-то потестить, то имейте в виду, что:

- включение антиалисингов и пр. замедляет рисование в разы
- рисование в картинку, которая не на экране может быть намного медленнее, чем рисование на экран, так как при рисовании в BufferedImage аппаратное ускорение часто недоступно в полной мере или вообще.

Comment: Это зависит от конкретного случая. Очень зависит от того, что конкретно рисуется. Но вообще, 1000 элементов не представляется проблемой.. думаю и 10.000 не должны стать большой проблемой.

Comment: 1кк элементов это 1 миллион :)<br>
10 миллионов - тоже никаких проблем не составит? :D<br>
С 1-10 тысячами и на canvas'e проблем 0<br>
Основу составляют простые точки и линии... ( вокруг которых все и пляшет )

Comment: Тогда надо было написать 1M :) А тут к и я подумал, что это просто опечатка. Да, с миллионом могут быть сложности. Если у вас 10 миллионов элементов, то какого разрешения у вас картинка? У вас выходит канвас на весь экран? Если ваши элементы больше, чем 1x1 пиксел, то, вероятно, они на самом деле не могут быть нарисованы все одновременно, а это значит, что вы ещё не всё соптимизировали, что могли бы.

Comment: Вы уверены, что надо **рисовать миллион** элементов ? Это лишь немного меньше, чем пикселов на экране. 

Может быть правильнее подумать об **оптимизации алгоритма**, производящего эти элементы ?

Comment: Canvas это не тупо "рисовалка"... :)<br>
Намого больше чем на 1 екран, даже не считал на сколько, но знаю что того что есть мне явно мало ^^<br>
Причем не с точки зрения производительности на этом этапе, а с точки зрения расширения функционала, вообще глубокого изучения отрисовки точками опыта в оптимизации жесткого кода и т.д. <br>
Банальный пример - хочу создать огромный изометрический уровень для игры, теоретически возможности того компа что сейчас, мягко говоря, не ограничиваются 1М эллементов...(это вообще смешно...)<br>
С 1М на канвасе небыло проблем... На java могут быть? О_о

Comment: А зачем это надо? Надо рисовать только ту область, которая видна пользователю. Т.е. нужно перед рисованием фильтровать элементы и отсекать те, которые не видны и по возможности отсекать перекрывающиеся. Тогда вам не понадобится гигантский канвас. Я думаю, что у канваса могут возникнуть проблемы с динамикой такого изображения. У явы тоже могут быть проблемы с производительностью, если рисовать что-нибудь безумно огромное... <br />
Уверен, что вы там делаете что-то не то..

Comment: Я все это прекрасно понимаю, но Вам уже видимо не понять моего спортивного интереса :)<br>
Да и я уже писал - основная трабла в том, что кож будет очень серьезно расширятся, и именно по этому я решил разобратся что лучше и т.д. до того как приступть к реальному написанию...<br> Банально - пусть дже есть 100тысяч ел. - при расширении кода ( анимашки, сложные пересчеты и т.д. и т.п. ) это будет тормозить...<br>
Я еще ничего неисправного не сделал, как отрисовать картинку с 1-10к элементов я вкурсе :)<br>
@avp причем тут алгоритм? был бы плохой 1М на канвасе не отрисовал бы, не? >_<

Comment: кстати - "javascript + canvas имеют какие-то серьёзные шансы против Java2D" - вполне возможно что имеют... во всяком случае за 3 часа гугления никакой инфы опровергающей эту мысль я не нашел и близко...<br>
Да и не сказал бы что html canvas медленный ( и этом мягко говоря ), просто хочется понять - стоит ограничится уже на этом или все-же есть лучшие решения..<br>
Вообщем чем дальше в поле тем меньше понимания, не суть, вопрос не актуален дальше сам разберусь :)